# Supervisord throws error: "couldn't exec /var/application/gunicorn_start: ENOEXEC"

Tags: django, gunicorn, supervisord

I was setting my server to run a Django web application, I have my *gunicorn_start* file that is working fine:

```
NAME="hello_app"                                  # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/webapps/hello_django/hello             # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/webapps/hello_django/run/gunicorn.sock  # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=hello                                        # the user to run as
GROUP=webapps                                     # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3                                     # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=hello.settings             # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=hello.wsgi                     # WSGI module name

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=-
```

but I can't make it starts automatically with supervisord because I get an error that says: **"couldn't exec /var/application/gunicorn_start: ENOEXEC"**

My supervisord file is:

```
[program:hello]
command = /webapps/hello_django/bin/gunicorn_start                    ; Command to start app
user = hello                                                          ; User to run as
stdout_logfile = /webapps/hello_django/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log   ; Where to write log messages
redirect_stderr = true                                                ; Save stderr in the same log
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8                       ; Set UTF-8 as default encoding
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution is really easy, you should add *#!/bin/sh* at the beginning of your gunicorn_start file. It should appear like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

NAME="hello_app"                                  # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/webapps/hello_django/hello             # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/webapps/hello_django/run/gunicorn.sock  # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=hello                                        # the user to run as
GROUP=webapps                                     # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3                                     # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=hello.settings             # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=hello.wsgi                     # WSGI module name

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=-
```